# Is it possible to use percentage values for width and height in image transforms?

Tags: image-transforms

I'm working on creating an image transform to handle retina images. I upload the 2x assets and need an image transform to create my images at 50% their original size. Since images on the site can be varying widths and heights I am currently forced to create a new image transform for each image ratio. Percentage values would cut this down to a single image transform for everything.

Comment: OT: Stuart, did you solve your `striptags` problem? (Sorry if I write here, will delete the comment later!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It’s possible to do this from your templates:

```
{% for image in entry.myAssetsField %}

    {% set half = {
        width: (image.width/2)|round,
        height: (image.height/2)|round
    } %}

    {% set halfUrl = image.getUrl(half) %}

    <img src="{{ halfUrl }}" srcset="{{ image.url }} 2x" width="{{ half.width }}" height="{{ half.height }}">

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I forget about being able to use math in these situations. Still, would be nice to see percentage values in the CP.

Comment: Added to The List.

Comment: Great, because I just realized that when this gets mixed with Matrix blocks it gets even more complicated. It works but it's just a mess of variables that make template code harder to parse for bugs.

Comment: Might want to consider moving chunks of code to separate [includes](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html) or [macros](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html). Feel free to use those features liberally – there’s no noticeable performance penalty.

Comment: Just wanted to chime in to say that, if you are not doing art direction, you don't needs `<picture>`. An image with srcset and size is enough: http://picture.responsiveimages.org/#when-to-use this article helps a lot with keeping your sanity http://ericportis.com/posts/2014/srcset-sizes/